# PHP Custom Session Handler - handling session_regenerate_id

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am writing a custom session handler which will encrypt the stored session data. The key would be generated at runtime and stored in a cookie (using the settings from session_get_cookie_params()).

This is all fairly straightforward, however I should be regenerating the encryption key when the session id is regenerated to provide protection against fixation attacks - but there is [no hook in the session handler API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) to call my code when this happens.

A potential solution would be to see if the sessionid has changed between reading and writing the session, however writing the session may occur after the headers have been sent - so I couldn't set a new cookie value with the new key.

Is there another way to infer when session_regenerate_id() is called? Presumably the existing session is closed and a new one created - does PHP call handler::open() again?

Is there another (otherwise transparent) solution I've not thought of?

**update**

Oddly, the documentation for [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) has a parameter which seems to provide exactly what I'm looking for. However my PHP 5.4.10 installation does not recognise the extra parameter (introduced in 5.5.1).

The session interface (on 5.4.10) is not called by session_regenerate_id()

Comment: Note that when I'm talking about fixation attack vulnerability I'm referring to the encryption key, not the session.

Comment: Would this help you? https://suhosin.org/stories/feature-list.html

Comment: Suhosin uses a static key for all sessions which is stored in the INI file. Hence anyone with a full backup of the site can decrypt the file, any PHP script running on the server which can read the session data can decrypt the data. Further as a solution it only works where suhosin can be installed.

Comment: Would browser sessionStorage solve the problem?

Comment: I can't imagine how.